# Angular + Rails beginner's questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm  learning angular for last two weeks. I think it's really interesting to work with frontend framework, I don't have expected that I'll have to create 2 separate complete apps :). I've some questions on you

1. what is the best method to manage models connections in angular like rails user.animals.where(...)

e.g. 
I have User model, every user has many animals.
On the page I want to show 
link table with Users animals and right table with all animals,
now I make two promises to animals controller once for users and once for all animals, it's double the queries number and is hard to manage when I want add a form for create a new animal, because i have to push new object into two models arrays in angular

further when every animal could have many toys and user can add only one toy pro animal of another user it becomes to be really complicated

I have to send json from rails controller and includes animals toys and also an array with users ids, then in view

```
ng-hide="(animal['users_ids'].includes(user.id)"
```

with this solution, when I create a new model I have to update toys model and also animals, could it be done simpler?

2. What is the best method to sync angular and rails model when the latter changes?

I could refresh page every x second, but it's not pro.

3. I've confirugred rails and angular to works with devise and oauth. My configurations works but I'm not sure if the solution is solid and safe

   ```
   Gemfile 
   gem 'devise'
   gem 'omniauth-facebook'
   gem 'omniauth-github'
   gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
   ```

rails generate devise:install

set up existing User model

```
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :github]

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end
    end
```

set up devise initializers

```
    config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true
```

set up onniauth initializers

```
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :facebook, ENV['APP_ID'], ENV['APP_SECRET'],
        scope: 'email,public_profile', info_fields: 'email,id,name'
    end
```

set up routes

```
    devise_for :users,  :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "sessions#create" }
    get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

sessions controller

```
      def facebook
        @account = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        sign_in @account
        render 'sessions/create', layout: false
      end

      def github
        @account = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        sign_in @account
        render 'sessions/create', layout: false
      end
```

app/views/sessions/create.html.erb

```
    <p>This view will now self-destruct</p>
    <script>
       try {
          window.opener.$windowScope.handlePopupAuthentication('<%= @provider %>', <%= @account.to_json.html_safe %>);
       } catch(err) {}
       window.close();
    </script>
```

and angular configuration

app/assets/templates/login.html.slim

```
    div.page-header
      h1 Log In

    div class="btn dash-subs login-btn" ng-click="authNetwork('facebook')"
      p Login With Facebook
```

app/assets/javascript/auth/authCtrl.js

```
    angular.module('myAPP')
      .controller('AuthCtrl', [
      '$scope',
      '$state',
      'Auth',
      function($scope, $state, Auth){

       $scope.handlePopupAuthentication = function handlePopupAuthentication(network, account) {
          $scope.$apply(function(){
            window.location.reload()
          });
       }

       $scope.authNetwork = function authNetwork(network) {
          var openUrl = '/users/auth/' + network
          window.$windowScope = $scope;
          window.open(openUrl, "Authenticate Account", "width=500, height=500");
       };
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `ng-change` directive in angular, whenever the input is changed you can trigger whatever function you want

You can find documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), and there are multiple examples else where too

Also, you can avoid making two requests one for users and other for animals, it can be avoided by using active model serializer in rails, it will really help

Here is a nice video for serializers, [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

Comment: Refreshing the page is always avoidable in Angularjs, If you go through this path be sure that there is always a better solution